# extracting features from all bounding boxes of Fast R-CNN

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I just installed Fast RCNN and have run the demo,

and I came to wonder if it's possible to extract features from all bounding boxes in the image (and do this for the entire dataset).

For example, if Fast RCNN detects cat, dog, and a car from an image,

I'd like to extract separate CNN features for each of cat, dog, and car.

And do this for tens of thousands of images.

The feature extraction example on Fast RCNN's Github (https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn/tree/master/examples/feature_extraction) seems to be the replica of feature extraction using caffe for the entire image, not each bounding box.

Could anyone help me on this?

UPDATED:

Apparently, feature extraction for each bounding box is done in the following part of the code from https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/lib/fast_rcnn/test.py:

```
# When mapping from image ROIs to feature map ROIs, there's some aliasing
# (some distinct image ROIs get mapped to the same feature ROI).
# Here, we identify duplicate feature ROIs, so we only compute features
# on the unique subset.
if cfg.DEDUP_BOXES > 0:
    v = np.array([1, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12])
    hashes = np.round(blobs['rois'] * cfg.DEDUP_BOXES).dot(v)
    _, index, inv_index = np.unique(hashes, return_index=True,
                                    return_inverse=True)
    blobs['rois'] = blobs['rois'][index, :]
    boxes = boxes[index, :]

# reshape network inputs
net.blobs['data'].reshape(*(blobs['data'].shape))
net.blobs['rois'].reshape(*(blobs['rois'].shape))
blobs_out = net.forward(data=blobs['data'].astype(np.float32, copy=False),
                        rois=blobs['rois'].astype(np.float32, copy=False))
if cfg.TEST.SVM:
    # use the raw scores before softmax under the assumption they
    # were trained as linear SVMs
    scores = net.blobs['cls_score'].data
else:
    # use softmax estimated probabilities
    scores = blobs_out['cls_prob']

if cfg.TEST.BBOX_REG:
    # Apply bounding-box regression deltas
    box_deltas = blobs_out['bbox_pred']
    pred_boxes = _bbox_pred(boxes, box_deltas)
    pred_boxes = _clip_boxes(pred_boxes, im.shape)
else:
    # Simply repeat the boxes, once for each class
    pred_boxes = np.tile(boxes, (1, scores.shape[1]))

if cfg.DEDUP_BOXES > 0:
    # Map scores and predictions back to the original set of boxes
    scores = scores[inv_index, :]
    pred_boxes = pred_boxes[inv_index, :]

return scores, pred_boxes
```

I'm trying to figure out how to tweak this to save the features, as we do with Caffe for features of the entire images, which are saved to a mdb file.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem. You already have the images annotated with the bounding boxes of the objects? Or you need to extract those BBoxes from unannotated images?

Comment: @FlavioFerrara I want to extract features from each of the bounding boxes.  Thus, each bounding box is considered a discrete image from which features are extracted. We can assume I already have the bounding boxes.

Comment: Then you don't need Fast-RCNN. It is an **object detector**, that is, a way to obtain the bounding boxes when you don't have. Just extract the patches and extract the features for each patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

During the process of determining the right bounding boxes, Fast-RCNN extracts CNN features from a high (~800-2000) number of image regions, called *object proposals*. These regions are obtained through different algorithms, typically [selective search](http://koen.me/research/selectivesearch/). After this computation, it uses those features to recognize the "right" proposals and find out the "right" bounding box. This is called *bounding box regression*.

Of course Fast-RCNN optimizes this process, but still has to extract CNN features features from many more regions than the ones related with the object of interest.

Shortly, if you were to save the variable `blobs_out` in the code snap you pasted, you will save the features relative to **all** the object proposals, including the "wrong" proposals. But you can save all that and then try to prune and retrieve only the desired ones. To save the features, just use `pickle.dump()`.

Look at the end of the `test_net` function, [here](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/lib/fast_rcnn/test.py#L324). The `nms_dets` variable seems to store the final boxes. There may be a way to take the `blobs_out` you stored and throw the undesired features off, but it doesn't seem so straightforward.

---

The simplest solution I'm able to think about is as follows.

Let's Fast-RCNN compute the final bounding boxes. Then, extract the relative image patches, with something like the following (I'm assuming Python):

```
img = cv2.imread('/path/to/image')
for bbox in bboxes_list:
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = bbox
    cut = img[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    extract_cnn_features(cut)
```

The feature extraction is identical to the entire image case:

```
 net = Caffe.NET('deploy.prototxt', 'caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
 # preprocess input
 net.blobs['data'].data[...] = net_input
 net.forward()
 feats = net.blobs['my_layer'].data.copy()
```

Of course this method is computationally expensive, since you are basically compute *twice* the CNN features. It depends on your requirements about speed and the size of the CNN models.

Comment: I think you're assuming that i got the boxes by something other than fast-rcnn. Let's assume that I obtained the bounding boxes from fast-rcnn. Couldn't I just manipulate the part where each bounding box is warped and passed to CNN so I can obtain the features for each box? (which is what I actually meant in the question)

Comment: that is, I eventually want to save the features (as in mdb with caffe)

Comment: Ok, now I got it better. I based my answer on the comments below your question. I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: apparently, the nms_dets turned out to be box sizes and the scores in each class for all proposals.. :(

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/tools/demo.py#L95-L109) code in order to prune the proposals. Then, you can go back to the saved features and try to retrieve the desired ones.